# How to redirect ILoggerFacade to ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, prism

I want write my logs to the ViewModel, so I can expose logs to the users.

First I bind View to ViewModel

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Logger}" AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

This is the ViewModel

```
private string logger;

public string Logger
{
    get { return logger; }
    set
    {
        logger = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Logger");
    }
}
```

Then, I create the customer logger class which implements ILoggerFacade,and override the CreateLogger method in Bootstrapper.

In Bootstrapper

```
protected override ILoggerFacade CreateLogger()
    {
        return new MainLogger();
    }
```

In Customer Logger class

```
public class MainLogger : ILoggerFacade
{
    public void Log(string message, Category category, Priority priority)
    {
        string messageToLog = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{1}: {2}. Priority: {3}. Timestamp:{0:u}.", DateTime.Now, category.ToString().ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), message, priority.ToString());
        //////??????//////
    }
}
```

And what should fill in ???????. I tried Import IEventAggregator to publish data to ViewModel, and directly import ViewModel here. Neither works, because CreatorLogger Method is called before container is registered. So how can I write logs to the ViewModel?

Comment: Do you want to display the textbox in the shell directly, or inside a view that you register in a region in PRISM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger should simply save the log message(s) and expose it in a property:

public interface IMainLogger : ILoggerFacade
    {
        List Messages { get; }
    }

```
public class MainLogger : IMainLogger
{
    public MainLogger()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; private set; }

    public void Log(string message, Category category, Priority priority)
    {
        string messageToLog = ...;
        Messages.Add(messageToLog);
    }
}
```

That's basically what a logger is supposed to do: Log messages. Now you want to display it inside some TextBox which is contained in a View that you inject into a region, right? To do that, you need to pass that logger to the Module of this region's view via constructor dependency injection. I am working with MEF, so I'm not too sure about how to do it with Unity, but it probably looks something like this, when you configure the container in code:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IMainLogger, MainLogger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ContainingTextBoxModule>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IMainLogger>()));
```

where the module takes and exposes the logger:

```cs
public class ContainingTextBoxModule : IModule
{    
    public IMainLogger Logger { get; private set; }

    public ContainingTextBoxModule(IMainLogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Then your ViewModel for the module can relay the message(s) and you can bind to it/them from your view.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks,I use MEF too. I'm relying too much on MEF, so I forgot basic things.